# Checkbox returns specific values to different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I assume has several issues. I need it to input different values in two cells based off of a CheckBox.

```
Sub YesNoChkBox()
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox, g As Integer, h As Integer, r As Integer
    Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

    With ChkBx.TopLeftCell
      r = .Row
      g = .Column + 2
      h = .Column + 3
    End With

    If ChkBx = 1 Then
        gr = "NO"
        hr = "NO"
    Else
        gr = "YES"
        hr = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I need the checkbox to input **NO, NO** into the two cells (2 and 3 columns over) if checked, and **YES, BLANK ("")** if unchecked respectively.

The reason I am using r,g,h is because I would like to just copy and paste the checkbox to different rows and have it automatically populate the corresponding cell (which will always be column G:H but rows 5:21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
If ChkBx = 1 Then
    Cells(r, g) = "NO"
    Cells(r, h) = "NO"
Else
    Cells(r, g) = "YES"
    Cells(r, h) = ""
End If
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for about an hour before I decided to post the question, it just so happens that I corrected the mistake with the exact same solution you provided, then I came back to the question to close it an saw your solution. How coincidental! Thank you for verifying!

Comment: Give yourself a pat on the back!